# Cannot use and found setTexture:resize SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sktexture

i have a problem with texture in SpriteKit game:

in `touchesBegan` i do:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

  SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

  if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"worm"]) {

    [node removeAllActions];
    SKAction *change = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"worm2"]];
    [node runAction:change];
```

this code works but the new texture "worm2" is scaled, and you see bad compared to how it should.

From Apple Documentation, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/setTexture:resize:

there should be the method:  `setTexture:resize:`

but as you can see from the picture that I put, this method is not present..
[image]

**What am I missing?**

thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggest from @user867635 `[SKAction setTexture:resize:]` is available from 7.1 .. so I found another solution to this problem:

when init the scene:

```
_texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"worm2"];
[_texture preloadWithCompletionHandler:^{}];
```

and after in `touchesBegan` call this texture as above, `preloadWithCompletionHandler` solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think `[SKAction setTexture:resize:]` is only available in iOS 7.1. Take a look at the [API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS71APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013973).

Maybe update Xcode to the latest version (5.1), if you are running an older version.

Comment: ooh thanks! I have not really seen! does not make much sense to use this if it is available only by 7.1, and the app will work on 7.0..

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
SKAction *change = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"worm2"]];
[node runAction:change];
```

is equivalent of changing the texture directly:

```
SKSpriteNode* sprite = (SKSpriteNode*)node;
sprite.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"worm2"];
// optional: update sprite size to match texture size
sprite.size = sprite.texture.size;
```

There's no need (and less efficient) to use actions to change a texture unless you want to delay the texture change.

Comment: thanks for the explanation on how not to use a SKAction to change texture!

Comment: i tried and the problem remains.. so i found other solution, check my answer please ;)